# C# Windows Service use Selenium to open Chrome browser to grab data

Tags: c#, windows, selenium-webdriver, service, selenium-chromedriver

I can't get windows service to open a Chrome browser. I am running the service as my main account which has admin credentials. It just hangs when it gets to

```
IWebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver("Drivers", chrOptions);
```

All the Selenium Code below.

```
ChrDir = @"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data";
ChrProDir = "--profile-directory=Profile 1";
ChrUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:99999/web/index.html";
ChrRecUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:99999/web/index.html#!/server/schedule";
ChromeOptions chrOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chrOptions.AddArgument(ChrDir);
chrOptions.AddArgument(ChrProDir);
IWebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver("Drivers", chrOptions);  // <----Fails here
browser.Navigate().GoToUrl(ChrUrl);

//Code will be here to grab data from website
```

I am using Selenium and it runs fine as a console application, but I must be getting some type of permission error. I had a similar problem accessing the network share, but that was fixed running the service as an admin user account.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Windows Services do not have the same access to the Windows graphics subsystem that an ordinary application does.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Maybe I can get Selenium to work for me in headless mode.

Comment: I managed to run `Firefox Nightly` from Windows Service (running under `System` account) via Selenium (`FirefoxDriverService`) after adding `options.AddArgument("-headless");` argument into `FirefoxOptions`.